# Timestamp display

Tags: c#, datetime, unix-timestamp

I've some issues with displaying a correct time. It display a not correct time and also everytime the same, also if the the times are not the same. (example: Time 1 - 2014-09-07 11:45:12 and time 2 - 2014-09-07 11:52:04, I'll get 04:12 for this two times). Only the hours and minutes may show, not the date.

This is what I'm using to calculate a time

```
public static int ToUnixTimestamp(this DateTime value)
{
return (int)Math.Truncate((value.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
}
public static int UnixTimestamp()
{
return (int)Math.Truncate((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds);
```

This is what I'm using to display the timestamp - There's no conversion needed because the full date insert into the database as a DATETIME (ex. 2014-09-07 11:45:12)

```
 response.Append(((DateTime)dRow["time"]).ToUnixTimestamp());
```

Whats wrong? Thanks for help!

Comment: Lots of things wrong. First, to motivate people to read your code it helps if you post it with proper indentation and spacing between methods. And the second method you post is missing the closing brace, and as far as I can see is not involved in your question.

Comment: Next, when something doesn't work, you should try to break it down into something simpler and test the simple parts. "response.Append(((DateTime)dRow["time"]).ToUnixTimestamp());" involves the database (?) value being as expected and your method working as expected. Break it down into those two parts - is the database returning what you expect, and is your method working as expected. If the database returns what you expect and your method is wrong, show a test case that does not involve the database.

Comment: I get the feeling that your database contains date/time as local date/time. That is usually a bad design decision, it leads to problems when accessed by users in different timezones. Dates and times in databases should usually be UTC.

Comment: Your first method has a parameter named "value". Give it a more descriptive name like "localDateTime" or "utcDateTime". Then ensure your method handles whichever parameter it is supposed to handle properly.

Comment: The places where you have "new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)" should probably be "new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).ToUniversalTime". Unix time is measured in seconds from Jan. 1 1970 UTC, not local Jan. 1 1970, although this a common kludgy way of doing it - instead of using UTC for everything some programmers use local time for everything, and it sort of works until timezone situations enter into the picture.